# How to achieve these bootstrap tabs

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

Asked a question prior regarding bootstrap tabs, however, I would still like to meet the same looks which can be found on this: http://beyondadmin-v1.6.0.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/profile.html. The issue I was originally facing was that the page would redirect it, ui-boostrap is an option however I was wondering how I can achieve the same level of design as found with the link listed above.

The code I submitted in the previous question was the following:

```
<div class="profile-body">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-flat  nav-justified" id="myTab11">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#overview" data-toggle="tab">
        Tab 
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-red">
      <a href="#timeline" data-toggle="tab">
          Tab Tab
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content tabs-flat">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="overview">
      <div class="row">
        <!--Information-->
      </div>
      <div id="timeline" class="tab-pane">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My previous question can be found here with the answer: 
[Bootstrap tab redirects me to another HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274560/bootstrap-tab-redirects-me-to-another-html-page)

New to bootstrap and angular, any help would be great! Many thanks!

Comment: you can use [**ngx-bootstrap tabs**](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs)

Comment: How so? As I said I want to get it to match the one in the beyondAdmin link.